# nested use of Apply/Map/MapThread in pure functions

Tags: dictionary, wolfram-mathematica

**1. My main question**

I have a function with two argument slots. I wan't to apply this function to 2 lists with different length's. I thought in this solution:

```
Map[Map[f[# &, #], b] &, c]
```

But it doesn't work. Why is that?

**Example**

```
f[x_, y_] := Sin[x y]


  b = {1, 2}
  c = {1, 2, 3}
```

The output seems pretty close of what i wanted but not close enough:

```
{{Sin[#1 &][1], Sin[#1 &][2]}, {Sin[2 (#1 &)][1], 
  Sin[2 (#1 &)][2]}, {Sin[3 (#1 &)][1], Sin[3 (#1 &)][2]}}
```

**2.** It seems that i only need to take the &'s out of the square brackets.

**a)** Is it so? Why?

**b)** how can i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the two arg form of function to name one of the parameters..

```
Map[Map[Function[ci,f[ci, #]], b] &, c]
```

Outer works great for this example, but named pure function args are useful for more general cases..Often they aid readability even if not strictly necessary.

Comment: Thank you.I'm trying to create a routine that receives a function, a list of arguments, and a "map of calculation" and outputs a list of results. I gave an example on [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15952918/table-tree-of-values).In this particular case, tha "map of calculation" can be obtained with outer

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Outer` as in :

```
Outer[Sin[#1 #2] &, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}]
(* {{Sin[1], Sin[2], Sin[3]}, {Sin[2], Sin[4], Sin[6]}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you. I was aware of outer. But in my case i needed something more general.This question results from another that i asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15952918/table-tree-of-values). My goal is to be able to apply a function to different kind of structured data. What i mean is that the each element of the output list has as arugments a "transformation" of the "arguments". In this case, that transformation happend to be covered by outer